# Why does this return the sum of the numbers from lower through upper?

Tags: python, function, recursion

I'm new to programming so please forgive me if this is a silly question. The code block returns the summation of lower through upper, but I am not sure why.

```
def summation(lower, upper):
   if lower > upper:
       return 0

   else:
      return lower + summation (lower + 1, upper)
```

In the past, I would have to write out code for each step of the summation like this:

```
def summation (lower, upper):
   result = 0
   while lower <= upper:
      result += lower
      lower += 1
   return result
```

This logic seems to be missing from the code block that uses summation recursively yet it still works. Any explanation would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The recursive version is using the unnamed return value here: `lower + summation(...` and is the equivalent of `result += lower` in the iterative version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just how recursion works. It's easier to see if I just prove it with induction: just assume that `summation` gives you the sum of all numbers in that range.

- Base case: if `lower > upper`, then obviously there are no numbers to be summed up, so the result is zero.
- For ease of imagination, now what happens if `lower == upper`? Then,

```
summation(upper, upper) = upper + summation(upper + 1, upper)
                        = upper + 0
                        = upper
```

which is what we want.

- Induction step: by construction, we have:

```
summation(lower, upper) = lower + summation(lower + 1, upper)
```

By our original assumption, `summation(lower + 1, upper)` gives us the sum of all number between `lower + 1` and `upper`. Replacing that onto the above equation, we have

```
summation(lower, upper) = lower + summation(lower + 1, upper)
                        = lower + ((lower + 1) + ... + upper)
                        = lower + ... + upper
```

which is exactly what we expect.

The idea is that if this function for some case, then it works for every case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example what your function call would expand into (pseudo-code):

```
def summation(lower, upper):
   if lower > upper: return 0
   else: return lower + summation(lower + 1, upper)

summation(0,2) = (if 0 > 2: 0 else : 0 + summation(0 + 1, 2))             #if False
               = 0 + summation(1, 2)
               = 0 + (if 1 > 2: 0 else : 1 + summation(1 + 1, 2))         #if False
               = 0 + 1 + summation(2, 2)
               = 0 + 1 + (if 2 > 2: 0 else : 2 + summation(2 + 1, 2))     #if False
               = 0 + 1 + 2 + summation(3, 2)
               = 0 + 1 + 2 + (if 3 > 2: 0 else : 3 + summation(3 + 1, 2)) #if True
               = 0 + 1 + 2 + 0
               = 3
```